# Wondering why sed isn't working with xargs like I expected

Tags: rhel5, sed, xargs

I am wondering why the following command wouldn't work:

`sudo find . -name index.htm | xargs -0 sudo sed -i 's/pattern1/pattern2/g'`

When ran the two commands separately, they worked as expected, `find` found all the files I was needing to change, and `sed` correctly replaced the text according to the regex (obviously when i ran the sed command separately i supplied a filename as an argument).  When running them together with xargs -0, I got

```
sed:
    ./index.htm
    ./folder1/index.htm
    ./folder1/subfolder2/index.htm
    ...
    ...
    ./lastfolder/index.htm: No such file or directory
```

I ended up using

```
sudo find . -name index.htm -exec sudo sed -i 's/pattern1/pattern2/g' {} \;
```

and it worked fine, I was just curious why using xargs didn't work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't use the `-print0` option with `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any spaces in the directory or file names?

Comment: a question is seldom an answer.